# Container div not properly... containing

Tags: html, css, containers

I just notice this when I put in a quick mock for a footer. My .container is sitting at the top of the page like this (Green highlighted in firebug):

[image]

This is my layouts file:

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %>">
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>

<div class="container">
  <%= render 'shared/alerts' %>
  <div class="main">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
  </div>
</div>

<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
```

Which shows that it's correctly opened and closed.

The only css applied is this:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 65px;
}
```

along with browser-width specific width sizing in media-queries.

This means that layout wise, the footer which is technically the last thing on the page, comes up to the top like this because it's below the container. Oddly however, everything inside .container is appropriately centered with margin: 0 auto. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: show is the CSS for all the elements inside the container. This is usually an issue of float clearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "Clear your floats".

When an element is `float:right` for example, it is in a way, removed from the flow of the layout. It won't push down anything below it (including the bottom of it's containing element) unless those things are also floated right, or `clear:right`. Clear basically says "ok, respect the bottom of all this floated stuff".

`clear:both` is used most often, and does just what it says.

Chris Coyier nails it with [this article.](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)

You can also build yourself a "Clearfix" if this is something you run into often in your layouts. [Here is a bunch of methods for doing that.](http://code-tricks.com/css-clearfix-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is  that you have some floated block level containers between the header and the footer, and the floats are not cleared.

As a result, the footer content is wrapping around the right most floated div.

You need to clear the floats probably after the sidebar element.

To be sure, I would need to see more of your HTML/CSS but the image gives a good clue.

As a quick fix, you could try adding `overflow: auto` to the `footer` container's CSS ruleset.